# Error in image_pull_secrets for private repository Airflow deployed in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-secrets

I have deployed apache airflow in azure kubernetes.

Helm repository of apache airflow: https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/chart

AKS version: 1.16.13

Once I have airflow deployed I have tested it with this dag:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.utcnow(),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'kubernetes_sample', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=10))


start = DummyOperator(task_id='run_this_first', dag=dag)

passing = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='default',
                          image="python:3.8-slim-buster",
                          cmds=["python3","-c"],
                          arguments=["print('hello world')"],
                          labels={"foo": "bar"},
                          name="passing-test",
                          task_id="passing-task",
                          get_logs=True,
                          dag=dag
                          )


passing.set_upstream(start)
```

It works fine. Now I want to use my own images. For that, I am using azure containers, and following this  guide: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/operator/kubernetes.html, I am using this code to create the secret to access to my azure registry:

```sh
kubectl create secret docker-registry testquay \
    --docker-server=quay.io \
    --docker-username=<Profile name> \
    --docker-password=<password>
```

I build my image and I test locally and it is working. I upload the image to azure container registry and I write the following dag:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.contrib.kubernetes import secret
import logging
import os
import sys
import traceback 

try:
    env_var_secret = secret.Secret(
        deploy_type='env',
        deploy_target='VERSION_NUMBER',
        secret='myregistrykey',
        key='VERSION_NUMBER',
            )
    default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': datetime.utcnow(),
        'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
    }

    dag = DAG(
        'jordi_test_get_secert2', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=10))


    start = DummyOperator(task_id='run_this_first', dag=dag)

    quay_k8s = KubernetesPodOperator(
            namespace='default',
            name="passing-test7",
            image='docker.io/test-pai-1',
            image_pull_secrets=env_var_secret,
            task_id="passing-task6",
            get_logs=True,
            dag=dag
        )


    start >> quay_k8s

except Exception as e:

    error_message = {
            "message": "An internal error ocurred"
            ,"error": str(e)
            , "error information" : str(sys.exc_info())
            , "traceback": str(traceback.format_exc())
        }
    logging.info(error_message)
```

And give me this error:

```py
 File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/kubernetes/pod_generator.py", line 272, in __init__
    for image_pull_secret in image_pull_secrets.split(','):
AttributeError: 'Secret' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Following this guide: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/operator/kubernetes.html

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from kubernetes.client import models as k8s
import logging
import os
import sys
import traceback 

try:

    default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': datetime.utcnow(),
        'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
    }

    dag = DAG(
        'jordi_test2', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=10))


    start = DummyOperator(task_id='run_this_first', dag=dag)

    
    quay_k8s = KubernetesPodOperator(
    namespace='default',
    name="passing-test7",
    image='docker.io/test-pai-1',
    image_pull_secrets=[k8s.V1LocalObjectReference('myregistrykey')],
    task_id="passing-task6",
    get_logs=True,
    dag=dag
)



    start >> quay_k8s

except Exception as e:

    error_message = {
            "message": "An internal error ocurred"
            ,"error": str(e)
            , "error information" : str(sys.exc_info())
            , "traceback": str(traceback.format_exc())
        }
    logging.info(error_message)
```

But give me this error:

```py
for image_pull_secret in image_pull_secrets.split(','):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

If I go to the Airflow documentation for the KubernetesPodOperator: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator/index.html

Say:

```py
 image_pull_secrets (str) – Any image pull secrets to be given to the pod. If more than one secret is required, provide a comma separated list: secret_a,secret_b
```

How is the correct way to write it?

Comment: You are giving "image_pull_secrets" a `secret.Secret` object instead of a string, as the type in the source code indicates. Try giving it `"myregistrykey"` instead

Answer (score 1):

Would ask for clarification as a comment but I don't have the reputation. So providing a solution with some assumptions.

1. Since you provided documentation links to the latest version of Airflow I'll assume you are using that.
2. The code you posted is unaltered.

Here your secret is named **testquay**

> ```
> kubectl create secret docker-registry testquay \
>     --docker-server=quay.io \
>     --docker-username=<Profile name> \
>     --docker-password=<password>
> ```

However you reference it as *myregistrykey* in the code you posted that is meant to follow the example you reference.

> ```
> image_pull_secrets=[k8s.V1LocalObjectReference('myregistrykey')],
> ```

It should reference the secret name according to the example.

```
image_pull_secrets=[k8s.V1LocalObjectReference('testquay')],
```

Also for the first DAG code, I don't believe you can pass a `Secrets` object in that manner. Those are meant to be injected into the k8s pod either as a volume or env variable at runtime. https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/kubernetes/secret.py#L35-L40